# Unable to view react routes in springboot after adding security

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

I have a reactJs/Spring Boot Application structured so that that react/front end piece is embedded in the java main project folder but operates independently of the backend during development.

[image: Project Structure]

I'm using the eirslett plugin to build my react project and copy the files into `${project.build.directory}/classes/public` directory when I build the spring boot application.

Before I built in security (OIDC) I as able to build the project and navigate around without any issues. Since building in security I can no longer navigate around my built project. So I'm guessing that I have misconfigured something in my security file that is blocking the routing in my app that was previously working.

The project builds and I get the login screen, but when OIDC returns the callback with the user token the app stalls and I get a 404 error that /callback doesn't exists. But all the routes exited before security...so what's happening?

Here's my spring boot config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private JdbcOidcBearerTokenFilter filter;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(@Value("${security.oauth2.client.wellKnownUrl}") String wellKnown
            , @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}") String clientId
            , @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientSecret}") String clientSecret
            , EaUserService usersService, LoginService loginService) {

        OidcService oidcService = new OidcService(wellKnown, clientId, clientSecret);
        this.filter = new JdbcOidcBearerTokenFilter(oidcService, usersService, loginService, "Authorization");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/error", "/403.html", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/media/**", "/static/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .addFilterAfter(new OAuth2ClientContextFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(this.filter, OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                /**ORDER MATTERS! - Least restrictive first**/
                .antMatchers("/api/login/**", "/static/**", "/classes/public/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/watersystem/public/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasAnyRole("DDW_ADMIN", "DEVELOPER")
                .antMatchers("/api/enforcementactions/**").hasAnyRole("DDW_ADMIN", "DEVELOPER", "DDW_STAFF")
                .antMatchers("/api/incidents/**").hasAnyRole("DDW_ADMIN", "DEVELOPER", "DDW_STAFF")
                .antMatchers("/api/reports/**").hasAnyRole("DDW_ADMIN", "DEVELOPER", "DDW_STAFF")
                .antMatchers("/api/utilities/**").hasAnyRole("DDW_ADMIN", "DEVELOPER", "DDW_STAFF");

    }

//Tried this but it resulted in a blank screen. W/O it I at least get the login page
/*
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer configurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
                registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("/css/", "/js/", "/media/");

            }

        };
    }*/
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the project structure once the app is built:

[image: project structure - post build]

POM- File for react build and copy

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>ea_react</workingDirectory>
                    <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v12.16.1</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.13.4</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes/public">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.basedir}/ea_react/build"/>
                                </copy>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: I "don't like" the `"/static/**", "/classes/public/**"` in your security config, please "try": `/public/**` instead.

Comment: I tried that and it still resulted in a 404